# MongoDb Update Array Of Object

Tags: mongodb

I have the MongoDb Document describe in the following playground
https://mongoplayground.net/p/7unPX_abybK

I desperately try to add an element in the links of a targetedEvent when the name of the targetedEvent is "RdvPris"  and that it has no link whith targetType:"missions"

So for the playground example , it should add an element under
"targetType": "t4"
and "targetType": "t5"

please help it is a real puzzle for me

Has anyone a solution ?
Thanx by advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: updated answer as per requirement

To add an element in the "**links**" array of a "**targetedEvent**" when the name of the "**targetedEvent**" is "**RdvPris**" and it has no link with "**targetType**" set to "**missions**", you can use this mongo query, it will update all matching document in collection.

```
db.collection.update({
  "targetedEvents": {
    $elemMatch: {
      "name": "RdvPris",
      "links.targetType": {
        $ne: "missions"
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  $push: {
    "targetedEvents.$[elem].links": {
      "targetType": "t30"
    }
  }
},
{
  multi: true,
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "elem.name": "RdvPris",
      "elem.links.targetType": {
        $ne: "missions"
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Here is the [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/G0dNpGS-YlC) link with example.

Feel free to add *_id* field accordingly.

Comment: Sorry Rawat But in your playground , in the "_id": NumberLong(31), the script should add a link under t3 and t4 since no link with targetType missions is present Beware that , you forgot the s to mission Can you tell me what sloud be modified then Thanx a lot for for help

Comment: oh okay, did not notice "mission" and "missions". here is the updated link https://mongoplayground.net/p/G0dNpGS-YlC